# Filter child-records (hasMany association) with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any possibility to filter the `hasMany` records from a model record? I want to get the active projects, grouped by the customer.

**Customer model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  projects:    DS.hasMany('project',{ async: true })
});
```

**Project model**

```
Docket.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  customer:    DS.belongsTo('customer', { async: true })
});
```

**Project route**

```
Docket.OrganizationProjectsIndexRoute = Docket.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  setupController: function () {

    var customersWithActiveProjects = this.store.filter('customer', function(customer) {
      return customer.get('id') && GET_ONLY_ACTIVE_PROJECTS_FROM_CUSTOMER?
    });

    this.controllerFor('organization.projects').set('filteredProjects', customersWithActiveProjects);
  }
});
```

## **Update**

I tried something like this but It does not work. I think this is a problem caused by asynchronous requests. But does it point in the right direction?

```
Docket.OrganizationProjectsIndexRoute = Docket.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  setupController: function () {

    // get customers because we group projects by customers
    var customers = this.store.filter('customer', function(customer) {
      return customer.get('id')
    });

    var sortedProjects;

    // loop through each valid customer and filter the active projects
    $.when(

      customers.forEach(function(customer){
        customer.get('projects').then(function(projects) {

          var filteredProjects = projects.filter(function(project){
            return !project.get('archived')
          });

          customer.set('projects',filteredProjects);
        });

      })

    ).then(function() {

        sortedProjects = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
          sortProperties: ["name"],
          content: customers
        });

    });

    this.controllerFor('organization.projects').set('filteredProjects', sortedProjects);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following could work:

**controller**

```
Docket.OrganizationProjectsIndexRoute = Docket.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  setupController: function () {

    var projectsController = this.controllerFor('organization.projects');

    this.store.find('customer').then(function(customers) {
      var promises =  customers.map(function(customer) {

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          customer: customer,
          projects: customer.get('projects').then(function(projects) {
            return projects.filter(function(project) {
              return !project.get('archived');
            });
          });
        });             

      });

      Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(filteredProjects) {
        projectsController.set('filteredProjects', filteredProjects);
      });

    });            

  }
});
```

**template**

```
{{#each filtered in filteredProjects}}
  Customer {{filtered.customer}}<br/>
  {{#each project in filtered.projects}}
    Project {{project.name}}<br/>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The trick is use [Ember.RSVP.hash](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#hash-of-promises) to group each customer by active projects.

Comment: Thanks, but the output is just "Customer Customer".

Comment: I will try to simulate this problem later in a fiddle

Comment: I think the problem is, that the objects, included in `filteredProjects` are promises. `console.log(filteredProjects)` returns this: http://gopeter.de/misc/promises.png . `length` of 2 is correct, because I've got 2 customers in my database

Comment: Thank you for the image, very usefull. You are right is returned an array of promises so is needed to use `RSVP.all` to wait all promisses to be resolved. Please, give a look in the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! I think I have to take a deeper look into RSVP :)

Comment: This is a good idea, the RSVP docs has been improved, these days.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have another little problem now: creating/updating/deleting child records (projects of customers) doesn't force ember to update the template.

Comment: I recommend you to create another question, so you can describe better the problem, and more people can help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541528/template-is-not-updated-when-child-record-change-hasmany-association :)