# Ember not updating template when model (in a hasMany association) changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I force Ember to update a template when a child record is added/removed to my model?

**Customer model**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  projects:    DS.hasMany('project',{ async: true })
});
```

**Project model**

```
Docket.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  customer:    DS.belongsTo('customer', { async: true })
});
```

When a project is added/deleted, this template should be updated:

```
{{#each filteredProjects}}

    <h2>Customer: {{customer.name}}</h2>

    <ul class="entries">

        {{#each projects}}

                <li>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button {{action "remove" id}} class="icon-close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="link" {{action "edit" id}} data-uk-modal="{target:'#project-modal'}">
                        <span class="before">{{number}}</span>{{name}}
                    </div>
                </li>

        {{else}}
            <li>No projects</li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>

{{/each}}
```

**Example actions (extract)**

```
remove: function (id) {
  this.get('store').find('project', id).then(function (data) {
    data.deleteRecord();
    data.save();
  });
},

save: function() {
  // create new record
  var project = this.store.createRecord('project', _this.getProperties('name', 'number', 'description', 'archived'));

  // set customer
  project.set('customer', this.get('selectedCustomer'));

  // validate and save if validation passes, otherwise show errors
  project.save().then(function () {
    _this.closeForm();
  }, function (response) {
    _this.set('errors', response.errors);
  });
}
```

## **Update 2**

I [openend an issue here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1577), but it hasn't been resolved until now.

Comment: Can you show the remove and edit actions?

Comment: I was wrong, updating works.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it? :)

Comment: I think you are using my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20517484/1846480), to fetch the data right? In that code is used `filter` and `map` that methods return new arrays (plain arrays) instances, when you use `this.store.find('customer')`, is returned a `DS.RecordArray` instance, and these classes update when some model is removed, or added. Plain arrays don't update.

Comment: You're right. But is there any way to solve this problem? Can I add an observer somewhere?

Comment: I also tried to use the `rerender` method if a specific controller property changes (it changes each time the user interacts), but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @Slevin, sorry for the delay. I was looking for a better way to solve this, but in the end, I am reloading the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, because you are using `map` to group the data, the returned array isn't a `DS.RecordArray` instance, so when a item is added or removed, the content isn't updated.

I think the easy way to handle it, is to reload the data, when a item is added or removed. So extract the method that load the data and call it in the `save` and `remove` action. Here I created a loadData method:

**route**

```
Docket.OrganizationProjectsIndexRoute = Docket.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.loadData();
  },
  loadData: function () {

    var projectsController = this.controllerFor('organization.projects');

    this.store.find('customer').then(function(customers) {
      var promises =  customers.map(function(customer) {

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          customer: customer,
          projects: customer.get('projects').then(function(projects) {
            return projects.filter(function(project) {
              return !project.get('archived');
            });
          });
        });             

      });

      Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(filteredProjects) {
        projectsController.set('filteredProjects', filteredProjects);
      });

    });            

  },
  actions: {
    remove: function (project) {
      var _this = this;
      project.destroyRecord().then(function() {
        _this.loadData();
      });
    },
    save: function() {
      // create new record
      var project = this.store.createRecord('project', _this.getProperties('name', 'number', 'description', 'archived'));

      // set customer
      project.set('customer', this.get('selectedCustomer'));

      // validate and save if validation passes, otherwise show errors
      projects.save().then(function () {
        _this.closeForm();
        _this.loadData();
      }, function (response) {
        _this.set('errors', response.errors);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**template**

```
{{#each filteredProjects}}

    <h2>Customer: {{customer.name}}</h2>

    <ul class="entries">

        {{#each projects}}

                <li>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button {{action "remove" this}} class="icon-close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="link" {{action "edit" this}} data-uk-modal="{target:'#project-modal'}">
                        <span class="before">{{number}}</span>{{name}}
                    </div>
                </li>

        {{else}}
            <li>No projects</li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>

{{/each}}
```

Some tips:

You can use `project.destroyRecord()` instead of `project.deleteRecord()` `project.save()`.

You can pass the project instance directlly to the action using `{{action "remove" this}}` instead of the id `{{action "remove" id}}` so no need to reload using:

```
this.get('store').find('project', id)...
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I placed my add/remove actions in my controller. Can I call the loadData method from a controller or do I have to place this methods in the route?

Comment: You can call in the controller, just the `setupController` will change, you will need to use `setupController: function(controller) { controller.loadData(); }` to call the controller method in the route