# Filtering child records in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have not been able to filter the childrecords of objects in **ArrayController**.

The structure of my models is like this:

```
var Shop = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('product')
});

var Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    shop: DS.belongsTo('shop')
});
```

Shop has many products, and product belongs to a shop. I would like to *filter* the childrecords of each parent based on a **Ember.TextField**. Filtering works if I'm only filtering the parent records based on a property they have, using a regexp.

```
productSearchResults: function() {
    var productSearchTerm = this.get('productSearchTerm');
    var regExp = new RegExp(productSearchTerm,'i');

    Ember.Logger.log('productSearchTerm', productSearchTerm);

    var filteredResults = this.map(function(shop){
        var products = shop.get('products');
        return products.filter(function(product){
            regExp.test(product.get('name'));
        });
    });
    // all items are returned always..
    return filteredResults;
}.property('products.@each', 'productSearchTerm')
```

## Edit

I tried to use promises here (source: [Filter child-records (hasMany association) with Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511910/filter-child-records-hasmany-association-with-ember-js) ), but it seems like this productSearchResults property is never accessed. I do not get any log output from here. In the template, I'm looping over filteredProducts and there is nothing there. If it's of any relevance, I'm using Ember 1.5.0 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba .

```
   productSearchResults: function() {
        var _that = this;
        var productSearchTerm = this.get('productSearchTerm');
        var regExp = new RegExp(productSearchTerm,'i');

        this.store.find('shop').then(function(shops) {
            var promises = shops.map(function (shop) {
                return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                    shop: shop,
                    products: shop.get('products').then(function (products) {
                        return products.filter(function (product) {
                            return regExp.test(product.name);
                        });
                    })
                });
            });

            Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function (filteredProducts) {
                _that.set('filteredProducts', filteredProducts);
            });
        });
    }.property('products.@each', 'productSearchTerm')
```

Comment: try out this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511910/filter-child-records-hasmany-association-with-ember-js][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511910/filter-child-records-hasmany-association-with-ember-js

Comment: I tried to adapt that above, but did not succeed yet. I can not even log anything inside the function, nor does Ember Inspector show any promises.